# HP officejet 7000 network printer printing totally wrong colours after automate of Ubuntu 20.04 lts

Tags: drivers, printing, hp, colors

I have had an HP officejet 7000 for 5 years and it has always worked perfectly with ubuntu.
I updated to Ubuntu 20.04 lts six months ago and it still worked fine.
Then after a routing 'security' upgrade it suddenly stopped printing colours correctly. Instead of normal colours it printed an apparently random range of colours.
Black and greyscale work perfectly.
I have another ubuntu computer running 16.04 lts and that does exactly the same. It was fine, now it has the same colour crazieness.
Printing over the network from my android smartphone works perfectly in correct colours.
Does anybody else have this problem?
I tried the HP printer drivers but these won't install.
Best
Richard Jannaway

Comment: Have you tried checking/updating/reinstalling the printer driver?

Comment: Two different machines have same issue with different OS. It appears to be a problem with the printer.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I tried updating the driver - not sure I did it right.  Trying the HP driver suit but it wouldn't install (unexpected comma or bracket at end). As I said printer works ok on android.

Comment: David and Matthias,
Many thanks for your thoughts. You might like to know that the problem has solved itself. After an automated Ubuntu Linux core update the printer is now working perfectly. it must have been a bug in the core. Dunno why it affected me and not others.